# How to prove that children in heap data structure are located at: 2*n and 2*n+1?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, heap

This is not homework question, I today learned heap data structure and I don't know how would I prove that relation is true. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't a result, it's more or less the definition of a Heap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prove by Induction:

1. children of root (1) -> child1= 2*1=2 , child2= 2*1 + 1 = 3 **true**
2. **Assuming** children of kth element are -> child1= 2k , child2=2k+1
3. **Prove** children of (k+1)th elements are child1= 2*(k+1), child2=2(k+1) + 1  (Prove this)

Proof of 3:
since children of kth elements are at 2k and 2k+1 (based on assumption) then, next two elements after are 2k+2 and 2k+3.

2k+2 = 2(k+1)   (first child for k+1 is proved)(a)

2k+3 = 2k + 2 + 1 = 2(k+1) + 1 (second child for k+1 is proved)(b)

from (a) & (b) --> thus 3 is valid thus child of element n are 2n and 2n+1

Comment: Do you know a proof without induction? Inductive proofs in general make little sense to me. I knew how heaps are working 3 years ago and today I tried to deduce these facts and it wasn't easy. I blame that on the fact that I learning this by inductive proof. Inductive proof doesn't create any intuition, no mental pictures and doesn't resonate with anything I already know.

Comment: @Pixar induction proof is very simple and easy to picture and apply once you understand it. believe it or not but there aren't many fundamental proof procedures out there. as far as I know there are 4 which are explained in here : http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~cytron/547Pages/f14/IntroToProofs_Final.pdf

Comment: Sure, proof by induction is simple and easy, but it doesn't make you remember things, because it is based on guess (guess first approach =) ). For example, you can easily prove 1+..+n = n * (n + 1) / 2 by induction, but I'd never teach a child this formula this way. It doesn't give you any intuition and completely heartless. I'd stick to induction only if I have no choice.

Comment: @Pixar hmm induction is not proved by guess. it uses `rule of inference` as its heart. the proof uses the most simple basics of our understanding. if you understand the induction then you realize how profound it is.  you can't say `it doesn't give any intuition`  just because you don't understand it

Comment: I understand induction and I didn't say that induction is proved by guess =)

Comment: @Pixar take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn . althrough its correct, its not really a complete and sound proof. it says you can just add numbers.

Comment: There are 29 answers in that thread. What is the answer you are reffering to?

Comment: If I had to teach someone about this formula, I'd rather show him the accepted answer than give him a prove by induction =)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof without induction, which is more intuitive and insightful from my point of view.
Here are 4 mental steps that proof this relation to me.

#### Flatten the tree.

Let's enumerate all the vertices of a tree in the following way:
[image]

Here is how these verices will look in array:

[image]

#### Segregate siblings in array.

We can notice that every two consecutive nodes (except the first one) are children of some common vertex:
1 **[** 2 3 **]** **[** 4 5 **]** **[** 6 7 **]** **[** 8 9 **]**

#### Build this array differently.

Now let's think in reverse order. What if we have an array of pairs: [(2, 3), (4 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)] and we want to aggregate them in a single array?

Let's say we have already placed the first 3 pairs:
**[** 2 3 **]** **[** 4 5 **]** **[** 6 7 **]**

What will be the index of the number 8 in the final array?
We know that we have placed 3 pairs already and they have taken 3 * 2 = 6 places in the beginning, so we will take the 7'th place.

If we code the placement of pairs, it will look like that:

```
pair<int, int> pairs[4] = { {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9} };
int aggregate[2 * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    aggregate[2 * i] = pairs[i].first;
    aggregate[2 * i + 1] = pairs[i].second;
}
```

The key part is this index of array *aggregate***[2 * i]**. In this code it is obvious to see why we multiply by **2** — we do it, because we have to **skip** the previous **i - 1** pairs.

#### Combine flattening of tree and aggregation of pairs

Now we need to see the correspondance between building aggregate array of pairs and flattening of a binary tree. Every pair of siblings has a parent. If two siblings (2, 3) and (4, 5) are adjacent in array, then theirs parents are also adjacent. Siblings (2, 3) have parent 1, siblings (4, 5) have parent 2, siblings (6, 7) have parent 3. So the **parent is like an index** in this array of pairs `pairs[4] = { (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9) }` and when we use **2 * i** to access its left child, we can think of *skipping* **i - 1** pairs of children generated by previous vertices.